# Where & how do i change the Ubuntu sound theme in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, sound, themes

I have looked all over the settings for a way to change the sound theme, but I can't find one. There is one spot in the settings where you can choose an alert sound, but that doesn't look like it would be what I want and it only gives the option of default. I have the Unity Tweak Tool,but there are no sound options present there. I downloaded a theme and placed the theme folder in `/usr/share/sounds`, but I don't know where to choose the theme.

This is for Ubuntu 16.04 and not a duplicate but its very similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to use the dconf editor. If it isn't already installed;

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then from the editor GUI, navigate to;

```
org > gnome > desktop > sound
```

You can set the theme name there. (Well, you can on Xubuntu 16.04, which is what I use).

Comment: This is a very good answer!

Comment: `WARNING: Be cautious while using dconf-editor, incorrect usage may break your system.` [Source](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/08/how-install-sound-themes-ubuntu-linux/)