# 2 different alert sounds playing at once in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, 17.10

I used the default alert sound in Ubuntu 17.04. When I upgraded to 17.10, the same sound played. When trying different sound settings, I clicked on a sound and now **I hear that sound + the old one**.
If I set "Alarm volume" to OFF, there's obviously no sound. 
If I set it to ON, I hear 2 sounds.

[image: my current settings]

Comment: I don't remember having the problem in 17.10, but I clearly have it with 18.04.

Comment: This problem is addressed in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1827842.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how reproducible this is but I was able to disable the default sound in 17.10.  Here's what I did:

1. [Change the sound theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863232/and-not-where-how-do-i-change-the-ubuntu-sound-theme-help-16-04#863236) to `gnome` using the dconf-editor (under `org.gnome.desktop.sound`).
2. Under Sound Effects in the Sound Settings (shown in your picture), disable alerts.

For good measure, I also logged out and logged back in between steps.

Now, I still get the alerts (at least, I do when I test it at the terminal), but I don't get two alert sounds.  It is also worth noting that I upgraded from Ubuntu GNOME, so I may have different sound themes available.

If you want a different alert sound than the GNOME default, you will probably need to make a new theme.  My themes were in `/usr/share/sounds` (each folder contains a theme).  You should be able to copy a theme, change the name in the new `index.theme`, and then add the alert sound you like (as described in [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1558/368917)).

Comment: What I did is simply set default value to ON under `org.gnome.desktop.sound` (but left  "Alert" on) and now I only hear the default alert sound.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@desilvai's answer didn't work for me, but it helped me find a workaround.
In dconf-editor, I changed org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds to OFF.
Now I only hear one sound. The drawback is that I can not customize which sounds it plays, but at least it is less ugly than having two sounds...