# Can't turn off sound notifications/alerts in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I really don't like alert sounds and want to turn them off. I have tried to turn of sound effects in system settings, but that doesn't work for some reason. I also deleted all the sounds in /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts, but the sound remains. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What alert sound has survived the turning off in system settings? Can you give an example of an event producing a sound?

Comment: One example would be when trying to use autocompletion in the terminal with tab. If there e.g. are two alternatives for the completion (or none).

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't exactly find a solution but something close to it. This post [2 different alert sounds playing at once in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980046/2-different-alert-sounds-playing-at-once-in-ubuntu-17-10) describes a similar problem and so I tried turning of all event sounds with dconf-editor in org.gnome.desktop.sound and now all system sounds are muted.