# 18.04 GNOME 3 no alert/bell sounds

Tags: gnome, sound

Following the advice of [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980046/2-different-alert-sounds-playing-at-once-in-ubuntu-17-10) to fix the double-alert-sound bug, I executed

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

this caused there to be no alert sounds at all. However,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds true
```

didn't restore the alert sounds, even after a restart. It seems that something permanently killed itself as a result of the first command. There are no alert sounds from AccessX sticky keys, emacs `C-g`, terminal tab completion, etc.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to get the alert sounds back? (Preferably in a way that fixes the aforementioned double-alert-sound issue). I need the bell to work for sticky keys. Everything looks normal in the graphical settings:

[image: Gnome sound settings showing normally]

Comment: The alert sounds can be heard when one of them are chosen in the sound settings, but they can't be heard anywhere else.

Comment: They've come back for a moment but they're gone again. This corresponded with me trying to modify the `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg` file, but restoring it didn't restore the original bell behaviour, even with a restart.

Comment: Another symptom I noticed is that the system audio cuts out whenever an alert sound should be played. For example, if I'm playing some music in the background then press `C-g` in emacs, the background music will cut out abruptly for a fraction of a second as emacs tries to send a bell.

Comment: I don't usually talk to myself so much, but another thing I noticed is that the alert sounds sometimes come back if I switch to another audio output device, then switch back to my original device (the one I'm actually listening to). I'm not simply listening to the wrong device, since all other sounds such as the aforementioned background music come through just fine. Not sure if this is a tenable workaround or if the alert sounds will kaput again soon...

Comment: Try changing sound file to the one that last 7 seconds and see if the last two seconds play after 5 second delay. I had a similar problem about six months ago but am not at my computer now.

Comment: So far the workaround (switching audio output devices) seems to work. I lose the bell sounds on restart but once I do the workaround, the bell sounds seem to persist until the next shutdown. It's things like this that make me feel that GNOME 3 is the Win Doze of Linux land.

Comment: I still use Unity on Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04 so I don't experience the common complaints.